# Android XML binding of MutableLiveData not working

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have an activity with a `CoordinatorLayout` which contains a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I have bind the title of the activity to the `title` property of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, like shown below(posting only relevant parts of code since the layout is too big):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel"
                  type="com.android.myapp.ui.activity.home.HomeActivityViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_behavior="com.android.myapp.ui.behavior.scroll.appbar.DisableableAppBarLayoutBehavior"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                            android:id="@+id/appbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            app:title="@{viewModel.pageTitle}"
                            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarTitleStyle"
                            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="85dp"
                            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBarTitleStyle"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <!--Remaining layout-->
</layout>
```

As you can see the `pageTitle` property is bind to the xml `CollapsingToolbarLayout` `title` property.

Now in the `HomeActivityViewModel`:

```
class HomeActivityViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var isToolbarExpandable = MutableLiveData<Boolean>() // For handling the expansion of toolbar on navigation. This works perfectly
    var pageTitle = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        isToolbarExpandable.value = true
        pageTitle.value = "Home"
    }
}
```

And in `HomeActivity`:

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeActivityViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivitySafaricomHomeBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_safaricom_home)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        homeViewModel = getHomeViewModel()
        binding.viewModel = homeViewModel
    }

    private fun getHomeViewModel(): HomeActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeActivityViewModel::class.java)
}
```

The page title is set correctly in this case. But the trouble starts when I try setting the title anytime after the Activity and the first child fragment is created(I am using `NavHostFragment`, so the first fragment is created and attached as soon as the activity is created). The only place I can change the the title is the `onCreate` on activity and `onCreate` life cycle methods of start fragment. I am using the viewmodel as a shared viewmodel to change title from all child fragments. I am getting the ViewModel in Fragments using:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(HomeActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

After that, whenever I try to change the title, it simple won't change. Whether it be on a button click, after a delay, on the next fragment, nothing works. The only working place is `onCreate` of Activity till `onCreateView` of first fragment. I added an observer for `pageTitle` in `HomeActivity`, but after the first change, even the observer is not being triggered. On debugging, I could see that it is the same instance of viewmodel that is retrieved, and the `pageTitle` is being changed actually, but it simply stops observing after creation. Any idea what is the issue here? Please help.

Comment: did you try to debug the generated code where `CollapsingToolbarLayout#setTitle(CharSequence title)` is used?

Comment: @pskink I checked now, and figured out that `@Override protected void executeBindings()` is not being called the second time either.

Comment: why is not called?

Comment: As I mentioned, the Observer I added in Activity is also not being called after creation. Hence I think, everything simply stops observing the pageTitle mutable live data. Which I have no idea why.

Answer (score 12):

`LiveData` doesn't work with `DataBinding` since it doesn't have a lifecycle.

After

```
binding.viewModel = homeViewModel
```

Try Adding

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

So, all together

```
binding.viewModel = homeViewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

Comment: I also had tried this yesterday, didn't work. Will update question.

Comment: Is there anyway you can share a sample project on this issue ?

Comment: If you don't set the lifecyle owner you will only get one state change as described.This is the correct answer.